# pandas automatically converting date

Tags: postgresql, pandas, time

I am extracting data from an excel file and storing it into a postgresql table.The excel file has a column which has date values ranging greater than 23:59:59.When I am extracting the data in pandas data frame ,these values are automatically getting converetd to a different format.
For eg:
If the excel sheet has value of time as '31:15:45' Pandas convert it to '"1900-01-01T07:15:45.437Z"'
the postgres table stores '07:15:45'.
I have tried keeping the value string using dtype as well as tried using converters.But,they were of no help.The time is always getting converted.
I want the time value to be taken as it is i.e. '31:15:45'.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't store a time value of `31:15:45`  as that is an invalid `time`. It sounds, as if you really want an `interval` not a "time"

Comment: Using inteval is something which I am concerned when using postgres.The time is getting converetd while pandas is reading the excel.I need to overcome that first.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, think this is more what you wanted so I edited my original answer.
If your column is of 'dt' type you could do the following:

```
df[new_col] = df[name_of_date_col].dt.hour + ' ' +df[name_of_date_col].dt.minute + ' ' + df[name_of_date_col].dt.second
```

otherwise just change it to 'dt' type with

```
df[name_of_date_col] = pd.to_datetime(df[name_of_date_col])
```

Then do the stuff above

Comment: I used dtype.The column name in excel is AVG Case Close (Time).So , I used dtype={'AVG Case Close (Time)':str}.But,still the time is getting converetd to a different format.

Comment: use object. this should do

Comment: instead of str should I use object?

Comment: yes. Additionally you could check the type of the column as you read it in

Comment: <type 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Answer (score 0):

Leave it as string. when you are reading excel file into pandas you can specify data type for a column. It is called `converters`
Check [doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
pandas.read_excel(my_file, converters = {my_str_column: str})
```

Comment: That's strange. If you specify the column name from the excel sheet, pandas should adhere to the requested dtype conversion, or throw up an error