# Pandas - Convert decimal date from read_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have converted some excel files using pandas in csv. I noticed that the date is in decimal format now. However, it is not clear to me how to convert to `datetime` or at least timestamp.

So the converted dates look like:

```
42794.741667
```

I have understood that before the decimal is the days from 1900, but I am not finding anything regarding the second part of the decimal number. A lot of questions suggest to directly convert from read_excel: [pandas automatically converting date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49548724/pandas-automatically-converting-date). However, I can not do that as the excel files are pretty complex and do not have a predefined structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excel dates are not days from 1970, they are days from 30-Dec-1899. (You may be thinking of Posix timestamps, which is seconds from 1-Jan-1970).

Excel reports day 1 as 1-Jan-1900 (which would imply an epoch of 31-Dec-1899) but Excel also thinks that 1900 was a leap year, which it wasn't, so Excel's count is off by one for dates between 1-Jan-1900 and 28-Feb-1900.

This behaviour is deliberate. In the early days, Excel was competing with the market leader, Lotus 1-2-3, which also thought that 1900 was a leap year, and by the time people began to care about it, it was considered too disruptive to fix.

You can convert Excel dates to Python `datetime`s that `pandas` will understand like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(1899,12,30) + datetime.timedelta(days=42794.741667)
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 28, 17, 48, 0, 28800)
```

If you paste 42794.741667 into an empty Excel spreadsheet and format it as a date, you can confirm the conversion.